# Do I need to use inheritance and classes for my OOP webscraper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, web-scraping, python-requests

I am currently writing python code that scrapes information from the web.
I have to scrape several sites, but there a two types of procedures:

- Directly scrape from the website
- Download pdf and scrape it with regexes

I consider the following 3 options, which one would be recommended?

**Option 1**
Use inheritance:

```
import requests
import PyPDF2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.url = None

    def get_text_from_pdf(self, page_number):
        self.download_pdf(self.url, './data/{}.pdf'.format(self.name))
        mypdf = open('./data/{}.pdf'.format(self.name), 'rb')
        fileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(mypdf)
        page = fileReader.getPage(page_number)
        text = page.extractText()
        return text

    def download_pdf(self, self.url, path):
        response = requests.get(self.url)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)

    def get_soup_from_url(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url)
        result = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result)
        return soup


class Website1(Scraper):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('website1')
        self.url = 'https://website1.com'

    def get_info(self, soup):
        '''
        Parse the html code through Beautifullsoup
        '''


class Website2(Scraper):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('website2')
        self.url = 'https://website2.com/some_pdf.pdf'

    def get_info(self, text):
        '''
        Parse the pdf text through regexes
        '''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Website1_Scraper = Website1()
    raw_info = Website1_Scraper.get_soup_from_url()
    Website1_Scraper.get_info(raw_info)

    Website2_Scraper = Website2()
    raw_info = Website2_Scraper.get_text_from_pdf(page_number=0)
    Website2_Scraper.get_info(raw_info)

    #Website3_Scraper, 4, 5 ... 10
```

**Option 2**

Only use the sub classes `Website1` and `Website2`and convert the methods of the `Scraper` class to regular functions

**Option 3**

Delete all classes and only use functions, such as: `get_info_from_website1()` and `get_info_from_website2()`

Comment: This question is slightly off-topic for code review although the question definitely has merits. The code review site is for open-ended feedback on real working code that you own or maintain. This question is opinion based and that makes it off-topic. What we can do is provide a code review of the code you have written. Please read through our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for a clearer idea of what we can answer and how we can answer.

Comment: Further, you have placeholder/theoretical values ("website1"), which degrade the value of a scraping review. These should refer to the actual website, and your title should say what you're doing ("scraping a directory for disenfranchised octopi"), not your review concerns.

Comment: You should use `Scrapy` if you want object oriented style scrapping. I have already suggested this on the few answers that I have given.

Comment: @VisheshMangla It's "scraping", not "scrapping"

Comment: Lol, English is not my first language.Happens often with me. But thanks, I couldn't have detect it otherwise.

Comment: We can only do a comparative review if you've actually included all three versions as implemented code, but we can consider option 2 and 3 as lines you've thought of as possible improvements. In that light there's nothing wrong with them. However, there are great parts of your actual code missing, making any answers/reviews you'd get on this likely to miss the actual point (the actual problems) of your code. Please take a look at the link provided by pacmaninbw to the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I see no benefit to any of these approaches. You're just making yourself write more code. All you need is one class that analyzes a website entered from a user. If you have a predefined list of websites that you need to scrape, then iterate over each website instead of using a class for each one.

Since you say there are two ways of accomplishing this task, you can have the user pass in what mode they want to use to get the information. Something like

```
website = Scraper("https://www.google.com", "DIRECT")
website = Scraper("https://www.website_here.com/articles/article.pdf", "PDF")
```

Then you build your class around it. You want your code to be easily accessible and usable by a user. As a first time user, I would have no idea if I should use `Website1` or `Website2`. What are the differences? Why should I use one over the other? You should always look at your code through the lens of a user.

Comment: Ok, and then use if/then logic to implement the specific scraping criteria for each website? For example:

`get_info(self):`
    if self.url == "https://www.google.com":
        return scrape_google()
    elif self.url == "https://www.website_here.com/articles/article.pdf":
        return scrape_website_here()`

Comment: @JeromeB No, scrape the website that's passed to the constructor. If you want to make the class flexible, do not create individual methods for certain websites.

Comment: But each website will have different tags to scrape from, for example if I am scraping the price of a product on amazon.com and on ebay.com, they will have different  structure to scrape (different tags in the html code).Where do I write the specific code for each website? Or do I try to put all specific code in method arguments, but I think it would be complicated to condense all that logic in a few arguments